# Hide an option in selectbox using css

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and I want to hide the last option of the select box ie option - 3

```css
select[name="test"]:not(optgroup) option:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="test">
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <optgroup label="emails">
    <option value="two">2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <option value="three">3</option>
</select>
```

But the above CSS code doesn't work.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to hide: The third option? The option with value "three"? The option with the text "3"? The last option? The question is a little ambiguous.

Comment: do you want hide the option no 3 or the last option?

Comment: @DBS I think 'option - 3' refers to third option? Please correct me if I am wrong. Cheers

Comment: In your example "option 3" is consistent. However my point was that if you had 6 options: `3,a,b,c,d,e` Would you want the third option (`b`) or the option with value `3` (the first option). As you can see by the varying answers below, people have had several interpretations of what you meant.

Comment: @DBS If I had 6 options then I would have told 'option - b' . The question clearly stated what I wanted. The answers are definitely varying to each other but it's serving the same purpose ie removing 'option - 3'. Sorry if my question left you in a ambiguous position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see my attempt below

```css
select option[value=three] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="test">
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <optgroup label="emails">
    <option value="two">2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <option value="three">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's better to give some sort of explanation so next time the OP can work out what to do, something simple like "I'm selecting the option with the value three and giving it display none so it doesn't appear" would work.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want is to hide the last direct `option` child of the `select` element:

```css
select > option:last-child { display: none; }
```

```html
<select name="test">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <optgroup label="emails">
    <option value="two">2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small edit on your CSS. :)

```css
select[name="test"] > option:last-child { display: none;}
```

```html
 <select name="test">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <optgroup label="emails">
    <option value="two">2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the value selector like this:

```css
option[value="three"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="test">
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <optgroup label="emails">
    <option value="two">2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <option value="three">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is the same answer as @Rahul from 25 minutes ago